# How can I print what was input onto a textarea by clicking a button in html

Tags: html, button, input, textarea

Hi I am trying to return back to the user what he input after he clicks the submit button but i dont know how to do so. I am working only with java and html in eclipse please i need help.

this is the code i have so far, i know its not much.

```
<p>Temperature</p> <input type= "text" name= "Temperature">
<br>
<h6>Temperature</h6> <input>
<br>
<button>Submit</button>
<textarea rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: You need to use javascript here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this : 
In your form :

```
<button id="button1" name="button1">Submit</button>
```

Code for retrieve the value and print it :

```
$("button1").click(function() {
  var temperature = $(":Temperature");
  var htmlString = $(temperature).html();
  $(#textarea).text(htmlString );
});
```

Hope this will help

Comment: but how do i use the code for retrieving, i cant just add it to the jsp can I?